# Null object reference error when writing the file (ByteArray) and returning Uri

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I wrote this function to save a file and return the file Uri. But the *root* and the *file* vars, are always empty so it throws a NPE at the end.

```
fun writeFile(context: Context, fileName: String, body: ByteArray): Uri? {
        val fname = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath}/ardata"
        val root = File(fname)
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs()
        }

        try {
            val file = File(root, fileName)
            file.writeBytes(body)
            file.setExecutable(true)
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
```

the *return* throws a NPE with the message:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This is how my variables look like in the end of the function

[image: variables]

How can I save a file (ByteArray) and return the Uri?

Comment: if you are write file then only at the end write Uri object=fileobj.getPath().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the return to Uri.parse and worked

```
    val fname = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath}/ardata"
    val root = File(fname)
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs()
    }

    try {
        val file = File(root, fileName)
        file.writeBytes(body)
        file.setExecutable(true)
        val obj = file.path
        return Uri.parse(obj)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
 val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                OutputStream fOut;
                File file = File(path, System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".mp4");
                    fOut = FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(byteArray);
        fos.close();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
return uri;
```

Comment: It still return NPE on the return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)  and the file is still empty